# Overlaps between markers and labels

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I've created an Atlas in which I use a duplicate of a polygonal layer. The father is showed as polygonal coverage, the child is showed as marker on polygon's centroid using *Centroid Fill* in *Symbol*.
I've also a points layer with which I show the label of every point.
When marker is near the point label the label cover the marker, in others situations I haven't problems.
[image]

[image]

The green polygons and the red marker are the same vector.
How I can avoid the overlaps?